# How to estimate weekly and daily seasonality for data with 15min frequency in Python?

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, statsmodels, multiple-seasonalities

I am relatively new to time series. My goal is to predict a few hours of data, measured every 15min based on three months of observations in Python. I assume I have daily and weekly cycles which I want to estimate and apply ARMA on residuals obtained from subtracting this seasonal trend. I am using *statsmodels-0.8.0*, the latest version from master branch.

I tried several approaches which did not work. Any input is much appreciated, if you can comment on possible errors or suggest further steps, or better approaches. The list of things I tried:

1. *SARIMAX* on the original series with seasonal period 96(number of 15min periods per day) kills my Jupyter notebook kernel.
2. *statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose* complains about 15 minute frequency, specifically *"freq T not understood"*.
3. residuals from subtracting trends obtained by running *bkfilter*, *hpfilter*, and *cffilter* are not stationary.
4. I tried to model $y_t = \alpha * y_{t-96} + \beta * y_{t-96*7} + ARMA(p,q)$ by passing lagged values to *ARIMA* as exogenous variables, but got a warning that *Likelihood optimization failed to converge*, and for some *p*, *q* values, coefficients of AR or MA coefficients turned out to be *nan*'s.
5. *periodogram()* from *statsmodels.tsa.stattools* gave me the highest frequencies at periods 62 and 9, but I do not know how to compute fourier coefficients and estimate the trend. 
   I am also concerned that spectral analysis approach is overfitting my data - do I get the same periods if I take a different three month of readings?

Comment: I am also having trouble with issue 4, except I got that with SARIMAX itself. I think the model can't be fitted if the order is too high, except that the correlogram is indicating such high orders.

Comment: For 2- I had the same problem: I had minutewise data so I used (Freq=60) in `seasonal_decompose` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities). The [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-seasonalities/info) has links to resources. The go-to solution is to model the seasonalities using multiple sinusoidal harmonics, then model residuals using ARIMA, possibly all with a Box-Cox transformation for good measure. This is known as a TBATS model. The `forecast` and `fable` packages for R contain functions for this, but I am not aware of any related functionality in Python. You may need to implement the algorithm per [De Livera, Snyder & Hyndman (2011)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jasa.2011.tm09771) yourself, or at least let yourself be inspired by the paper.